# Common Lisp: How to pass a keyword argument iff it has been passed to me

Tags: common-lisp, keyword-argument, optional-arguments

Time and again I find myself in the situation that a function A needs to call function B with or without keyword arguments, depending on whether such keyword arguments have been given to function A.

Maybe a silly MWE is easier to follow: let's ask a boy called Tommy how his day at school was:

```lisp
(defun answer (&key (math "boring" math-tested?)
                    (physics "heavy" physics-tested?))
  (if math-tested?
      (if physics-tested?
          (format t "I got an ~A from math and a ~A from physics!" math physics)
          (format t "I got an ~A from math." math))
      (if physics-tested?
          (format t "I got an ~A from physics." physics)
          (format t "Math was ~A and physics was ~A." math physics))))

(defun father-son-talk (&key (math nil math-tested?)
                             (physics nil physics-tested?))
  (format t "Hello Tommy, how was school today?~%")
  (cond ((and math-tested? physics-tested?)
         (answer :math math :physics physics))
        (math-tested?
         (answer :math math))
        (physics-tested?
         (answer :physics physics))
        (t (answer))))
```

This works as intended but it is irksome for several reasons:

1. The calls to `answer` are basically repeated. If `answer` had several normal arguments in addition to the keyword ones, I have to be extra careful to do the same in all four cases. Worse yet when maintaining such a thing.
2. The complexity grows exponentially with the number of keyword arguments. What if the father would ask about English, geology and Tommy's lunch as well?
3. Further confusion can easily arise if the father and son have different default arguments (one might be tempted to write `(answer :math math :physics physics)`).

**Question:** Assuming that `answer` is a part of the interface I have to conform to, how can I simplify `father-son-talk`? Ideally, I would like something like

```lisp
(defun father-son-talk (&key (math nil math-tested?)
                             (physics nil physics-tested?))
  (format t "Hello Tommy, how was school today?~%")
  (answer :math (math math-tested?) :physics (physics physics-tested?)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common solution to this is `apply`:

```
(defun father-son-talk (&rest all-options &key math physics)
  (declare (ignore math physics))
  (format t "Hello Tommy, how was school today?~%")
  (apply #'answer all-options))
```

and if `father-son-talk` doesn't need the keyword arguments itself at all, you can simplify this even more

```
(defun father-son-talk (&rest all-options)
  (format t "Hello Tommy, how was school today?~%")
  (apply #'answer all-options))
```

A nice trick you can do with functions like this is to say that you do want keyword arguments, and also you accept *any* keyword arguments, and then pass them on to implementation functions:

```
(defun father-son-talk (&rest all-options &key &allow-other-keys)
  (format t "Hello Tommy, how was school today?~%")
  (apply #'answer all-options))
```

This is like the previous version except that, for instance `(father-son-talk 1)` is now an error: the arguments to it must all be keyword arguments.  Which you want depends on whether `answer` might expect non-keyword arguments, so both can be interesting.

There is also a nice case like this where a function itself wants keyword arguments but wants the set to be extensible: the single `&rest` argument the function gets is in fact a property list, so you can do things like this:

```
(defun foo (&rest plist &key &allow-other-keys)
  ...
  (getf ':x plist 1) ...)
```

Comment: I've added a couple of other cases to your answer which I think are worth mentioning: I hope that's OK.  If you don't like the changes obviously just reject the edit.

Comment: Hi @tfb, I am fine with your changes. Thanks for this "collaboration" :-)

Comment: Thank you both. This is the sort of lispy solution I was hoping for: not very plausible at the first sight but very clever at the second sight thanks to everything being lists.